# Authenticating Django-Website with external Json Web Token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have the following setup:

- Apache Webserver running a Django Frontend Webpage
- Application Server running a Django REST Framework

I now have to integrate the the Django Frontend into a 3rd party project which is written in java and angular. The authentication is completely handled by this  3rd party.

Users login over LDAP and create a JWT token.

Is it possible to simply receive the token in Django and authenticate the User after successfully decoding the token? And how would this work with the @login_required decorator when I have protected functions?

Is there some sort of project where I can orient on, or do I have to write all myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a built-in `User` model to store usernames. This enables me to login the user when authentication is successful and then use Django functionalities such as `@login_requested` as you'd normally use them.

Below is a sample code (without the code for REST authentication).

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def user_login(request):
    ''' User login '''

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:index'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        # Your code for authentication here
        # authenticate =  .... 

        if authenticate:
            # Get user // create one if it doesn't exist yet
            user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username)
            # Login user - @login_required decorator can be used after user has been logged in
            login(request, user)
            next = request.POST.get('next', '/') if request.POST.get('next') else '/'
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Authentication failed', extra_tags=forgot_password)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:login'))
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/login.html', {})
```